# PHP Date Recurrence Library?

Tags: php, class, datetime, rfc2445, rfc5545

Ruby, Java, and Python all have several very good libraries which allow you to handle [rfc2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt)'s rrule very well.

I've done an extremely comprehensive search for a class/library which will handle the rrule and return dates of recurrence, however I haven't found 1 library in PHP will do it.

I am going to begin to write a PHP library which similar functionality to Ruby's [ice_cube](http://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube), however before I begin I just want to ensure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

So that brings me to this question, am I reinventing the wheel? Did I fail to find a library already written which handles date recurrence in PHP?

Comment: The parser of http://phpicalendar.org seems to handle rrules. Maybe you can leverage it.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that, however the code is not reusable really, nor very optimized.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After a thorough search I've determined that there is most likely not an open source date recurrence library written in PHP, so I have written my own.

I'm pleased to announce that I have released the initial version of a date recurrence library called [When](http://github.com/tplaner/When).

Comment: Looks nice at first glance.  Do you plan on supporting the ability to pass a raw RRULE string into the class with a start date?  That would be ideal in cases where the UI passes that back from a recurrence control.  No need for everyone to figure out the parsing step individually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have gone ahead and implemented the feature. If you have any further suggestions feel free to message me or add it as a issue on github.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I will check that out the update and provide feedback -- this came at the perfect time for a project I'm working on.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, this looks excellent. I'm converting a Rails website to PHP, and the Rails site used an Occurrence gem. Glad to see you've provided a PHP library for this purpose. Kudos to you!

Comment: evolve, correct me if I am wrong, but this doesn't seem to be support excluded dates? Fantastic library though, it's been very useful

Comment: @andrewtweber The current version does not, however the next version will include a method to exclude dates (such as holidays).

Comment: @evolve: Thank you so much! I was actually writing my own class and stumbled on this! thank you so much!

Comment: @evolve Hi! I've been playing around with three php recurrence libraries today, where none of them seems to do the trick. One of them is is yours which I'm very fond of, but it bothers me that I need to pass a RRULE or an options array to the constructor and the values are fixed. I have a rfc5545 string but I want to modify it later on. simshaun/recurr seems to do this part but it can't generate occurences. Also it would be nice to be possible to get next occurence on infinite rules. I'll open up issues on github when I get some time, hit me up if you want help. All in all, nice library!

Comment: When my start date is on 31 of the month , the following months that doesn't contain 31 are skipped . Is it configurable ?

Answer (score -1):

Gud work but it seems that the INTERVAL PARAM does not works well with WEEKLY,MONTHLY,YEARLY frequencies,there are differences in result as compared to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt